# How do linked list work if nothing has been added to them and you try to print that variable

Tags: c, linked-list

I have a linked list and want to print it out in the end. My questions is, if the linked list variable in the struct is left untouched and nothing is added to the list, if I try to print using `while(school->list!= NULL)` will this work?

Note: I have no made the list NULL at any point, I have just allocated name and not touched the list.

```
struct School{
    char *name;
    Student *list;   <--- Linked list
} School;


struct Student{
    char *name;
    Student *next; 
} Student;
```

Now if I want to print this list will this work?

Edit: I changed `(school->student != NULL)` to `(school->list != NULL)`

Comment: Accessing an unallocated memory is resulting in an *undefined behavior*.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I am not accessing it though, I am just checking it is NULL with while(school->list!= NULL). So if I didnt use the list, would it be NULL?

Comment: @John If you did not set it why would it ever be null?

Comment: If you used `calloc()` to allocate the memory, there is a big chance to be `NULL` in typical environment. If `malloc()` is used, the value is indeterminate.

Comment: if you never assign anything to a variable, its value is undefined. It may be 0 (NULL), it may be any garbage. Using such value to make a decision produces undefined behavior. Ways to avoid this: use static memory, use calloc, use memset, use constructor-like function.

Comment: @Arkadiy Should I set student -> list to NULL every time or should I set list->next?

Comment: @John - You should set `School->list` to `NULL` before you add any students to it. That value signifies that the list is empty.

Comment: @John, to print out the list, you just need to traverse it in a loop. For example, `struct Student *stu; for (stu = School->list; stu != NULL; stu = stu->next) { printf("%s\n", stu->name); }`.

Comment: Yes, please set the `list` to NULL

Answer (score 0):

Well see this example to print a list:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct test{
     int code;
     struct test *next;

};

void pri(struct test *); // As you dont whant to change the values of list.
void cre(struct test **);// This put list at the start
int main(void){
   struct test *head;
   head = NULL; // you start from null.

   cre(&head,5);
   cre(&head,10);
   pri(head);   

   return 0;
}

void cre(struct test **head,int x){
     struct test *tmp;

     tmp = malloc(sizeof(struct test));
     tmp->code = x;
     tmp->next = (*head);
     (*head) = tmp;


}

void pri(struct test *head){
     while(head){ // while we dont reach end of list.
          printf("%d ",head->code);
          head = head->next; // Go to our next element
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

I hope this program help you to print lists.This works of course if we insert an element to our list at the end etc.Make a draw to your paper to understand lists better.